# Reference c++ library in wcf service

Tags: c#, c++, wcf, configuration

I been searching this for a long time but haven't seen an answer.

I'm referencing two dlls, which are a C++ library API for .NET, in a wcf service library, it works fine when invoking the wrapped method from wcftestclient. But when self hosting the library in a websercice it says"can't find assembly xxx.dll (it's one of the c++ API dll) or one of its dependency". But I can see the dll it says missing is auto copied to the bin/debug folder for the host webserive project. Also, I can host the library in a simple console project in which calling the wrapper method has no problem at all.

I hope this is a simple config setting that i'm missing to specify in the web config file, anyone has any suggestion? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I spent almost three days on this problem and now it's resolved. In case this can help someone else who might have the same situation here is why.
The two c++ library .net api dlls are late binding so it won't look for its dependency until runtime. I even tried to registry the whole external library package in GAC and it didn't help; this was because one of two .net api dlls is a weak assembly hence CLR won't even bother looking for it in GAC. What I did was create a static constructor for the service and within the static constructor load the late binding assembly into AppDomain. I am using `Assembly.LoadFrom(string filePath)` method (other methods are available on Assembly class to do this). Now I can host the service on IIS and consume it in any client. So if clr is complaining it can't find an assembly but you can see it in the bin/debug folder, it's probably a late bind assembly which needs to be pre-loaded into the AppDomain; the good thing about AppDomain is you only need to load the assembly once and it will never unload an individual assembly.