# C++ DLL being called from WCF Service Application not working when deployed in IIS 8?

Tags: c#, c++, wcf, iis, dll

I am calling a C++ DLL using DLLImport. The code is in a class library project which is being called from a WCF Service Application.

```
 [DllImport(dllPath, SetLastError=true)]
 public static extern IntPtr CDSEngineConstructor();


 [DllImport(dllPath, SetLastError=true)]
 [return: MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.I1)]
 public static extern bool InitialiseDSEngine(StringBuilder pSB, IntPtr pDSEngine, StringBuilder pName, [MarshalAs(UnmanagedType.LPArray)] string[] ppListToLoad, UInt32 usiNumber);
```

I get a IntPtr on successfully calling the dll's constructor.

```
IntPtr pEngine = CDSEngineConstructor();
```

I use the above value as a parameter to call another initialize method in the dll.

```
if (!InitialiseDSEngine(sb, pEngine, sbReportingName, lstTyping.ToArray(), 10))
        throw new Exception("Failded to initilaise the search engine. please check the logs")
```

**EDIT**: the log files are not getting created!

The above method runs fine when I run my WCF in VS2008 development server. But after deploying the same in IIS 8, the above method returns false which means it fails to initialize and I cannot proceed further.

The DLL was built with Release mode in x86. My Class Library Project is also built with same Active configuration.

I have also tried to install C++ redistributable 2008 in the server. The IIS is setup to run 32 bit applications.

I am unable to find a solution and reason for this behavior. Querying for the same returns results where the dll itself is not loaded. But I'm able to load the dll correctly in this case.

Let me know if I have missed any information.

Comment: can you add some code and show things here not as screenshots but inline text?

Comment: @Hayt I have edited the question as you asked

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26979025/reference-c-library-in-wcf-service